# UIAlertView showing under KeyWindow's subview

Tags: ios, uialertview

I've add a custom view on keyWindow. How can I show an UIAlertController upon the custom view? (Right now the alert just pop under my custom view.)

```
let customView = CustomView()
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.addSubview(customView)

let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Error", comment: ""), message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think is better if you do not add a view directly to a windows, here some reason:

- One is the problem you are experiencing
- If you are deploying on target <=iOS7 windows doesn't rotate, so you can find your overlay view in a wrong position

To avoid that if you really want to add the custom view, use the `rootViewController.view` property.

```
let customView = CustomView()
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController.view.addSubview(customView)
```

I did not test it, but the custom view should be under the alert since it is in the rootviewcontreller hierarchy.

Comment: I've tried it. Work perfectly! Thank you sooooo much :)